How sensitive are bathroom sink drain seals to very slight angles in the drain pipe?
I got a new counter + faucet for my bathroom vanity and am reinstalling the drain.  The drain hole is in a slightly different place than previously, and this results in the plumbing connection to the drain hole being at a very slight angle that seems to be making it nearly impossible to create a leak-free connection where the rubber gasket on the drain assembly meets the sink's drain hole. (reinstalling plumbing after counter upgrades has been one of my biggest challenges with renovations in general for this reason, and i'd love to learn how to do it better!)

My situation is very similar to the one posted here (including the fact that i've followed all the steps in the same linked video), but I have not yet tried sanding the edge of the hole on the basin which i suspect will help quite a bit.
My one other thought is to add an accordion pipe connection which will allow me to (hopefully) fix the angle, though that will i think require a cut and re-weld at the purple section so that I can have the length i need to add it.  I have also seen folks on here recommend against using those.
My primary question though is, in general, I would have assumed that I can simply choose a sink and then adapt the plumbing to it without loads of difficulty, but is that not necessarily the case?  I don't have many degrees of freedom in this situation since most of the connections are welded (the threaded connection at the p-trap did help), so I guess when I do a counter upgrade i should in general be prepared to potentially have to replace the whole plumbing assembly below the sink, or install an accordion pipe?  I would like to do the same counter upgrade in my other bathroom but this has me wondering about whether i should instead look for something that more closely matches the original.
One other note is that the new counter does not have an overflow drain, so it occurred to me that i wouldn't actually need the holes in the drain pipe above the rubber gasket, and if I could somehow seal them then the rubber gasket connection would not be a failure point (i think).  Would love any feedback on whether/how that could be a solution here as well.

Thanks!

Perfect alignment is the idea.  Very slight misalignment will probably seal.  By shortening the pipe into the wall a bit and slightly turning the P-trap, alignment should be perfect.

Perfect illustration of why I prefer slip-jointed traps (that can be easily adjusted to be straight) rather than glued traps, unless I'm pouring concrete over the trap.

Accordion connectors are a quintessential example of "I want to save myself 5 minutes/dollars today, because the future is someone else's problem". If I needed to service 50 units ASAP and didn't care about code or clogs or cleaning, only metric being "doesn't immediately leak or back up"? Then a box of accordion connectors will spare me loads of measuring, thinking, and fetching different parts. It's almost never the best way, and is frequently preloading something for later anywhere between "irritation" and "catastrophe".

That's not where the putty goes (under the flange, on top of the sink. the bottom has a gasket). The tail piece goes on first, before you even drop the sink down on the counter; that points where ever it wants to end up, which is usually pretty straight. Then you deal with the slip joint crap. - No overflow? then it shouldn't have a stopper : wrong tail piece, that prob came with the (wrong) faucet; shouldn't be a stopper, nor a hole for its lever arm.

The best solution would be to cut away the white PVC trap, install a trap adapter on the stub of pipe protruding from the wall

a new slip-joint style trap

and an extension tube, if necessary, for spanning the vertical gap between the new trap and the existing sink tailpiece.

Choose a trap adapter that matches your existing piping type -- I've shown an ABS model above, but you may need the PVC equivalent.
This arrangement will allow the trap to both telescope in and out of the wall and also swing; the combination of the two movements will make it possible to set the trap opening perfectly below the sink outlet.
Photos: homedepot.com
